# sys.exit function doesn't end the program

Tags: python, python-keyboard

there's my code:

```
import sys
import keyboard
import rotatescreen
from time import sleep
pd = rotatescreen.get_primary_display()
angel = [90, 180, 270, 0]
for i in range(2):
    for x in angel:
        pd.rotate_to(x)
        sleep(0.5)
if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
    sys.exit(0)
```

So the program is working very well, doing his task, but the last 2 lines just don't seem to work. When i press 'p' the program just finishes his work instead of stopping.

Comment: last two lines don't appear to matter since whether or not `keyboard.is_pressed("p")`, the script ends successfully with status `0`.

Comment: I believe the `is_pressed()` function checks to see if the key is pressed _at that exact moment_.  If you pressed it earlier, the function will not detect that.

Comment: You need to create a handler for that key combination with an action to execute. For whatever keyboard module you’re using, look up something like “global hook.”

Comment: Generally speaking, lines of code are executed in order. That part is after the `for` loop, and will only check at the very end, after the loop is done.

Answer (score 1):

You want to listen for the keyboard event as close to the "execution" of your operation as possible. In your case, that's in the nested loop:

```py
for i in range(2):
    for x in angel:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
            sys.exit(0)
        pd.rotate_to(x)
        sleep(0.5)
```

I would also give the documentation a read through, specifically this: [Common patterns and mistakes](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#common-patterns-and-mistakes)